# Passing parsed variables into different models form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a products scaffold set up, and I just created a new foo controller and view. In my foo controller I parse a url, and get back an arry of objects. How can I pass each of these variables into the products form as defaults?

my controller:

```
     require 'net/http'
  require 'json'

def index
    if params[:commit] == "Add Product"
      @productId = params[:q]
      @resultsReceived = true
      if 
          url =  URI.parse("url" + params[:q].to_s)
          @response = JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get_response(url).body)
      end
    else
      @resultsReceived = false
      @response = []
    end

     respond_to do |format|
        format.html
      end
end
end
```

My current index

```
<%= form_tag("/foo", :method => "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:q, "Enter Product Number") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Add Product") %>
<% end %>

    <% if @resultsReceived == true %>
        Title:   <%= @response["product"]["title"] %>   </br>
        ID_Str:   <%= @response["product"]["id_str"] %> </br>
        Image Url:  <%= @response["product"]["image_url"] %>    </br>
        Base Item Price:  <%= @response["product"]["base_item_price"] %>    </br>
        Current Item Price:  <%= @response["product"]["price"] %>   </br>
        Seller Name:  <%= @response["product"]["mp_seller_name"] %> </br>
        Description:    <%= @response["product"]["descr"] %>    </br>
    <% end %>
```

I want the variable above to be passed to my already existing products from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to move the access of the other data from your index action  to either your your new action,  or an action you create 'new_prefilled'  possibly.  It would helpful if the attributes matched (the stuff you get from the url has the same attribute names as your product model)

i.e.

```
def new_prefilled

  if url =  URI.parse("url" + params[:oid].to_s)
    @response = JSON.parse(Net::HTTP.get_response(url).body)
  end
  @product = Product.new(@response['product'])
  render 'new'
end
```

Then you'd have to add a route,

```
get '/products/new/:oid' => 'products#new_prefilled'
```

Then in your index action,  you would do this:

```
if params[:commit] == "Add Product"
  redirect_to "/products/new/#{params[:q]}"
end
```

So you would render your new products view,  but it would be pre-filled with that data you got from the other site.